# Automatic delta logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have a query Q1 (stored as a view V1), the results of which we store at table T1.

I was wondering if there is some way to provide an automatic delta logic to a T1. Meaning, that each time a row of any of the data sources of Q1 get changed(I/U/D), T1 gets modified in such a way that the underlying query is correct.

One way I can imagine this possible is to make sure each row of T1 is associated (with further columns, or even tables) with every key of every table Q1 relies on. Then, have at each of those tables a trigger which keeps a trace of keys and rowversion modified. Then, when the recalculation time comes, the set of T1 rows dependent on at least one modified key is (re-)calculated.

This is difficult enough for a specific query. But what about making an automated way? That is, make a proc which takes a view name as a parameter, and implementing this.

I understand that this sounds enormously difficult - at the very least, it seems I'd need a full SQL-server parser to deduce table names.

On the other hand, I can't be the only one who has thought this. Delta logic is very useful in tables with many more reads than writes, eg transaction tables.

I guess indexed views are an implementation of this, but with limited functionality (many things cannot be used, most notably subqueries).

Of course, I wouldn't ask someone to develop something MS hasn't done...for me. So the question is: **Is automatic delta logic already available?**

Comment: `we have a query Q1 (stored as a view V1), the results of which we store at table T1.` You have the logic the other way round. Query / View is derived from Table

Comment: The query can be complicated code that reads from any number of tables. I have "saved" the query logic on a view, and I use this code to populate the table. As in, select * into T1 from V1. The thing is, how to do this smartly....

Comment: ok. that make more sense

Comment: Indexed view is exactly what you described, i.e. the database stores a copy of data and maintains/keeps it in sync with the source automatically. You are right, indexed views are limited. I don't think there is something generic out of the box.

Comment: The big problem with such generic task is that it can create a significant extra load on the server. Indexed views are limited, because it allows engine to keep them in sync with the source efficiently. When the view's query is complex you'll have to re-run the complex query in full for each change in the source table(s). It can be very expensive.

Comment: Or very cheap, contrary to its alternative of reading everything everytime. I understand the risks and the importance of careful consideration on each case - but can it be done?

Comment: [Change Tracking](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1819/using-change-tracking-in-sql-server-2008/) - is a light-weight feature which provides a synchronization mechanism between two applications. In other words, it tracks a table for net DML (INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE) changes that occur on a table, so that an application (like a caching application) can refresh itself with just the changed dataset.